# Every point in a metric space has at least a neighborhood?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading about topology and I came across this statement:

Every point $x$ in metric space $(X,d)$ has a neighborhood, which a neighborhood of $x$ (denoted $N(x)$) is defined as there exists $\delta >0$ such that the open ball $B_{\delta} (x) \subset N(x)$

The proof just says that take $N(x)= X$ as your neighborhood. Anybody can shed some light on how you can take $X$ be your neighborhood and ensure that every open ball around $x$ will lie completely in $X$?

Comment: What is your definition of $B_\delta(x)$? I have difficulty imagining any that doesn't make $B_\delta(x)$ a subset of $X$ _by definition_.

Comment: yes, points in $X$ whose distances are less than $\delta$ away from $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $\delta>0$ we have that $B_\delta(x)\subseteq X$. Therefore $X$ itself is a neighbourhood of any point $x\in X$.

Recall that $B_\delta(x)=\{u\in X\mid d(x,u)<\delta\}$. It follows immediately that $B_\delta(x)\subseteq X$.

Comment: While that may be true, @Daniel said that $B_{\delta}(x) \subset N(x).$ But then if $B_{\delta}(x)$ happens to equal $X$, doesn't this imply that $B_{\delta}(x) = X \subset N(x)$? and then $N(x)$ can't be a neighborhood since it consumes $X$

Comment: Since we already took $N(x)$ to be $X$, we immediately get that $N(x)=X$.

Answer (score 3):

In the space $X$ *everything is inside $X$*, it is necessarily open, and contains $x$.

But you can also consider the open ball of radius 1 around $x$.

Anyway, this $N(x)$ in our class denoted the set of *all* neighborhoods of $x$:
$$N(x):=\{ U\subseteq X \mid \exists\delta>0:B_\delta(x)\subseteq U\}$$

Comment: by the book I am using the $N(x)$ is just simply a neighborhood. According to my book your definition would be called something like a complete system of neighborhoods around $x$